# From Matlab to Python Code [z,index]=sort(abs(z));

Tags: python, matlab

i am trying to convert code from matlab to python.
Can you please help me to convert this code from matlab to python?

in matlab code

z is list and z length is 121

z= 7.0502    5.8030    4.4657    3.0404    1.5416         0   -1.5416   -3.0404   -4.4657 
-5.8030   -7.0502    7.5944    6.3059    4.8990    3.3662    1.7189         0   -1.7189   -3.3662   -4.8990   -6.3059   -7.5944    8.2427    6.9282    5.4611    3.8122    1.9735         0   -1.9735   -3.8122   -5.4611   -6.9282   -8.2427    9.0135    7.7027    6.2075  4.4590    2.3803         0   -2.3803   -4.4590   -6.2075   -7.7027   -9.0135    9.9185    8.6576    7.2038    5.4466    3.1530         0   -3.1530   -5.4466   -7.2038   -8.6576   -9.9185   10.9545    9.7980    8.4853    6.9282    4.8990         0   -4.8990   -6.9282   -8.4853   -9.7980  -10.9545   12.0986   11.0885    9.9947    8.8128    7.6119   -6.9282  -7.6119   -8.8128   -9.9947  -11.0885  -12.0986   13.3133   12.4632   11.5988   10.7649   10.0829   -9.7980  -10.0829  -10.7649  -11.5988 -12.4632  -13.3133   14.5583   13.8564   13.1842   12.5910   12.1612  -12.0000  -12.1612  -12.5910  -13.1842  -13.8564  -14.5583   15.8011   15.2238   14.6969   14.2594   13.9626  -13.8564  -13.9626  -14.2594  -14.6969  -15.2238  -15.8011   17.0207   16.5431   16.1227   15.7875   15.5684  -15.4919  -15.5684  -15.7875  -16.1227  -16.5431  -17.0207

Matlab code :  [z,index]=sort(abs(z));

after the code
z =  0         0         0         0         0         0    1.5416    1.5416    1.7189    1.7189    1.9735    1.9735    2.3803    2.3803    3.0404    3.0404    3.1530    3.1530    3.3662    3.3662    3.8122    3.8122    4.4590    4.4590    4.4657    4.4657    4.8990    4.8990    4.8990    4.8990    5.4466    5.4466    5.4611    5.4611    5.8030    5.8030    6.2075    6.2075    6.3059    6.3059    6.9282    6.9282    6.9282    6.9282    6.9282    7.0502    7.0502    7.2038    7.2038    7.5944    7.5944    7.6119    7.6119    7.7027    7.7027    8.2427    8.2427    8.4853    8.4853    8.6576    8.6576    8.8128    8.8128    9.0135    9.0135    9.7980    9.7980    9.7980    9.9185    9.9185    9.9947    9.9947   10.0829   10.0829   10.7649   10.7649   10.9545   10.9545   11.0885   11.0885   11.5988   11.5988   12.0000   12.0986   12.0986   12.1612   12.1612   12.4632   12.4632  12.5910
12.5910   13.1842   13.1842   13.3133   13.3133   13.8564   13.8564   13.8564   13.9626  13.9626   14.2594   14.2594   14.5583   14.5583   14.6969   14.6969   15.2238   15.2238   15.4919  15.5684   15.5684   15.7875   15.7875   15.8011   15.8011   16.1227   16.1227   16.5431   16.5431  17.0207   17.0207

and index is

index =   6    17    28    39    50    61     5     7    16    18    27    29    38    40     4     8    49    51    15    19    26    30    37    41     3     9    14    20    60    62     48    52    25    31     2    10    36    42    13    21    24    32    59    63    72     1    11    47    53    12    22    71    73    35    43    23    33    58    64    46    54    70    74    34    44    57    65    83    45    55    69    75    82    84    81    85    56    66    68    76    80    86    94    67    77    93    95    79    87    92    96    91    97    78    88    90    98   105   104   106   103   107    89    99   102   108   101   109   116   115   117   114   118   100   110   113   119   112   120   111   121

so what is the [z,index] in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to return the index? If you don't, you could use:

```
z = abs(z)    
new_list = sorted(map(abs, z))
index = sorted(range(len(z)), key=lambda k: z[k])
```

where x is the output and z is the list.

EDIT: 
Try that now

Comment: in matlab after this code  [z,index]=sort(abs(z)) 
script is using z and index for different lines. so i need both

Comment: @TevfikÖnen Ive updated it. This will now output the index as well as a sorted list.